# How to define SQLAlchemy models with DeferredReflection while allowing reading a pickled metadata?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I want to reflect the database tables, however I do not want the engine to be set at the time the models are declared. At some point after declaration, the engine is created and if a pickled metadata file exists, it should be used instead of reflecting the tables.

There is no issue with `DeferredReflection` when the pickled metadata is not used and the tables must be reflected, however I get the following error when I read the metadata and do not call `DeferredReflection.prepare`.

`sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class __main__.Foo is a subclass of DeferredReflection.  Mappings are not produced until the .prepare() method is called on the class hierarchy.`

```py
import pickle
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeferredReflection
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import configure_mappers


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///test.db")

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(
        sqlalchemy.text(
            """\
    create table if not exists foo (
        id int primary key,
        description varchar(255)
    );
    """
        )
    )

Base = declarative_base(cls=DeferredReflection)


class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
```

I can reflect the tables the first time and save the metadata, everything works.

```py
Base.prepare(engine)

with open("metadata.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(Base.metadata, f)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

with Session() as session:
    results = session.execute(sqlalchemy.select(Foo)).scalars().fetchall()
    print(results)
```

However on the second time running the program, I try to read the metadata from the file and get the error previously mentioned. I tried to use `configure_mappers()` after setting the metadata, and even setting the metadata for the registry of the `Base` class.

```py
with open("metadata.pkl", "rb") as f:
    metadata = pickle.load(f)
    Base.metadata = metadata
    Base.registry.metadata = metadata
configure_mappers()
```

What pattern could I use to solve this issue?

Comment: Please refer to the discussion on github where maintainers of SQLAlchemy have discussed how to best approach
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9942